# Система кодирования или хэширования

Tags: любой-язык

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что возвращает строку следующего формата: `f0c1c071-dc11-4032-b7a2-6f10ccf9f94d`. И как это можно раскодировать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это UUID. Никак не раскодировать, это просто имя. Идентификатор.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать, куда смотреть. )))